# Package naming conventions for domain object models

Tags: c#, java, naming-conventions, package

What are some good package naming conventions for domain specific object models.  For example, say you have a **Person.java** POJO, would you put it in a **mydomain.model** or  **mydomain.entity** or **mydomain.om** (object model) package.  The idea is to separate the MVC model objects from the domain object model.  Our MVC based application has a **model** package that contains behavior but using that package to contain our domain object model seems inappropriate and potentially confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use "com.mycompany.domain" personally, but that might not be the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to organize your packages vertically instead of horizontally to seperate functionality.

Eg.

```
com.foobar.accounting.model.*
com.foobar.accounting.view.*

com.foobar.invoicing.model.*
com.foobar.invoicing.view.*
```

may be better than

```
com.foobar.model.accounting.*
com.foobar.model.invoicing.*

com.foobar.view.accounting.*
com.foobar.view.invoicing.*
```

Answer (score 1):

The package name you choose is irrelevant.  model vs. domain vs. vo vs. foobar is all fine just as long as your team is all on the same page.  I agree that this package should only contain POJO domain objects with no significant business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that, be careful in the naming convention of your namespaces. I've seen cases where namespace names where duplicated in different assemblies. Talk about confusion.